# why my condition expression for attribute not exist fails in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDB table has a primary key as `id`. **The same id will be used to query a record.**

Now I want to insert a record with `id` and `originalURL` as attributes, I want to insert this record if and only if the `id` and `originalURL` doesn't exist in the table.

Update :- `ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(id) AND attribute_not_exists(originalURL)"` will only works in the context of primary key,[according to docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)**(You can perform a conditional put operation (add a new item if one with the specified primary key doesn't exist)** ,so `attribute_not_exists(originalURL)` is there or not it doesn't make a difference.**so i need either a solution where both the conditions work or originalURL also act as a key**

```
router.post('/', async function (req, res, next) {

  urlId = await nanoid(8);


  //const hashids = new Hashids('this is my salt')
  //urlId=hashids.encode(1)
  console.log('jatin', urlId);
  // urlId=uuidv4();

  const { longURL } = req.body

  const params = {
    TableName: 'url',
    Item: {
      "id": urlId,
      "originalURL": longURL
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set originalURL = :y",
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(id) AND attribute_not_exists(originalURL)"
  }
  dynamoDb.put(params, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).json({ error: error });
    } else if (Object.keys(data).length === 0 && data.constructor === Object) {
      res.status(200).json(
        {
          urlId,
          longURL,
          status: 'success'
        })
    }

    else {
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Please try again' });
    }
  })
});
```

as of now even if i try to send a request with sam original URL which is already present it successfully adds the record which I don't want.

Comment: So `urlId` is also same? Seems to me you are generating random `urlId`?

Comment: @Marcin  Yes, I am generating random urlId, urlId is not same for any record, my condition is to add record only if urlID say xyz and original URL say google.com is not present in the table from before, is there a way that conditional expression can work for that originalURL attribute too

Answer (score 1):

For `putItem` api you can have conditional expressions. According to the [Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)

> **ConditionExpression**
>
> A condition that must be satisfied in order for a
> conditional PutItem operation to succeed.
>
> An expression can contain any of the following:
>
> Functions: attribute_exists | attribute_not_exists | attribute_type |
> contains | begins_with | size
>
> These function names are case-sensitive.
>
> Comparison operators: = | <> | < | > | <= | >= | BETWEEN | IN
>
> Logical operators: AND | OR | NOT
>
> For more information on condition expressions, see Condition
> Expressions in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No

also the same scenario has been explained in This document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites

> The PutItem operation overwrites an item with the same key (if it
> exists). If you want to avoid this, use a condition expression. This
> allows the write to proceed only if the item in question does not
> already have the same key.
>
> ```
> aws dynamodb put-item \
>     --table-name ProductCatalog \
>     --item file://item.json \
>     --condition-expression "attribute_not_exists(Id)"
> ```

Comment: Your references are correct but they are not of any use! because my question is related to 2 conditions joined by AND operator, also the primary key attribute condition should seems to work so i need either a solution where both the conditions work or originalURL also act as a key

Answer (score 1):

Check if this resolves the problem

```
import { marshall } from "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb";

const params = {
    TableName: 'url',
    Item: {
      "id": urlId,
      "originalURL": longURL
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValue: marshal({
       ":originalURL": originalURLVariable
       ":id": idVariable
    }),
    ConditionExpression: "id <> :id AND originalURL <> :originalURL",
    UpdateExpression: "set originalURL = :originalURL",
   }
```

Comment: canot use import statement outside module is the error it shows

Comment: @JatinMehrotra sure, just to illustrate that you need import marshall at begin of your file.

Comment: Another observation, that you need use marshall to put your item. So your prop Item, in params object, need marshall, or you need create a object like on doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property

Comment: ![Marshall](https://i.imgur.com/t07sB8e.png)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html#marshall-1